# Traefik err too many redirects loop by forcing SSL redirection

Tags: traefik

I'm running on Kubernetes a Traefik Ingress Controller version 1.5.2.

I set at the level of the Ingress the Kubernetes security annotation: `ssl-redirect: true`

Once I do this and I try to reach the service via the web browser I get the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. My configuration is the following:

The AWS ELB forward the port 80 to HTTP while the port 443 is forwarded to HTTP. Traefik listens to this HTTP port.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question more than two years old. Probably the OP has already solved his problem by now. Anyway, I will give an answer because it is a quite common situation.

What was happening is a recursion during the destination rewriting. The original request is forwarded to a destination that, after one or more forwards, is forwarded again to the same destination. In the case of the posted question, port 80 has been redirected to the very same port 80 (alias HTTP), in an otherwise endless loop.